# ActiveResource::BadRequest error when trying to save after one update to a primitive attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

I am currently working with a REST API that has an object with an attribute "name."

```
item = person.find(id)
```

I can loop through the item's attributes without any problem and one attribute is, indeed, "name." However, when I try the following:

```
item.attributes["name"] = "New Name"
```

I can confirm that the attribute "name" has been updated, yet after calling

```
item.save
```

results in an ActiveResource::BadRequest (400) error. Has anybody encountered a problem like this before?

Thanks!

I tried the above and I also tried

```
item = person.find(id)
item.name = "New Name"
item.save
```

Finally, per suggestion, I tried

```
item.update_attribute(:name, "New Name")
```

and omitted item.save since the save is performed inherently.

It seems that no matter what I try, I continue to see the following stacktrace:

```
ActiveResource::BadRequest (Failed.  Response code = 400.  Response message = Bad Request.): 
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:84:in `update_data'
```

Where Line 84 is the event where the ActiveResource object is being updated.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails version 4.2.0. Active Resource version 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [attributes=](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes%3D) is deprecated on the latest stable version of Rails. The last existing version (v3.1.0).

Instead, you can use [update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute) to update the record's attribute:

```
item.update_attribute(:name, "New Name")
```

and `update_attribute` will save the record (if valid), so you don't have to call `save` on it.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried update_attribute, to no avail (same error).

Comment: can you show your full code snippet? also which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me. The stack trace is posted above and I am trying to get a more verbose one as we speak.

Comment: Can you post the full controller's code? Along with your strong parameters.
Also, the full stack trace means everything from your rails log

Comment: Thank you so much, K M Rakibul Islam. I was unable to find the logs easily because one of our team members had added a gem that overrode the traditional Rails logging. I found out the issue and it was completely unrelated - I failed to convert an attribute to an acceptable type, so my json was being formatted improperly. 

This is my first post. I will try to be more helpful in the future in providing my question along with necessary information. Thanks again.